# Declare a same variable name in derived class while other in super class as static variable

Tags: oop, inheritance

Can I declare a same variable name in derived class while the other is in super class as static variable?

```
class A
{
    static int x;   
   A(int a)
   {
     x=a; 
   }   
}
class B extends A
{
   int x;
   B(int b)
  {
    x=b;
   }
}
```

Comment: Which language is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C#. I don't know about Java. If you reference x from class A members, it accesses the static variable. If you reference x from class B members, it accesses the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Java as well. If you reference x from class B members, it accesses the instance variable.

However, the code you've written would give a compilation error as follows:

```
Main.java:21: error: constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;
    B(int b) {
         ^
    required: int
    found: no arguments
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

This is because you are using a parameterized constructor, and the parameterized constructor of the super class is not called yet. You can see this [here](https://ideone.com/UsCxeT). To prevent this, call `super(x)` to initialize superclass members inside the constructor.